# Framer Motion Exit Animation Not Working When Abstracting Components

Tags: next.js, framer-motion

I am trying to learn Framer Motion by making a todolist with Redux and Nextjs. The `exit animation` is not working with `Animate Presence` when the List Item is extracted out onto its own component.

Exit Animation Works with this

```js
export default function TodoList() {
    const dispatch = useAppDispatch()
    const todos = useAppSelector((state) => state.todo.todos)

    return (
        <AnimatePresence initial={false}>
            {todos.map(({id, ...props}) => (
                <motion.div key={id} initial={{ opacity: 0 }} animate={{ opacity: 1 }} exit={{ x: -300, opacity: 0 }}>
                    ...ToDo_MarkUp...
                </motion.div>
            ))}
        </AnimatePresence>
    )
}
```

But when I extract out the logic and Markup of List Item into it's own component, the exit animation doesnot work

```js
export default function TodoList() {
    const todos = useAppSelector(selectFilteredTodoIds)

    return (
        <AnimatePresence initial={false}>
            {todos.map((id) => (
                <motion.div key={id} initial={{ opacity: 0 }} animate={{ opacity: 1 }} exit={{ x: -300, opacity: 0 }}>
                    <TodoListItem id={id} />
                </motion.div>
            ))}
        </AnimatePresence>
    )
}
```